# How to make scope for model, that has two foreign keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have models `Account` and `Transaction`.

And model `Account` has two foreign keys in `Transaction`.

transaction.rb:

```rb
  belongs_to :credit_account, class_name: 'Account',
    foreign_key: 'credit_account_id', optional: true
  belongs_to :debit_account, class_name: 'Account',
    foreign_key: 'debit_account_id', optional: true
```

Also, transaction have columns `debit_amount` and `credit_amount`.

account.rb:

```rb
  has_many :debit_account_transactions,
    class_name: 'Transaction',
    foreign_key: 'debit_account_id',
    dependent: :nullify
  has_many :credit_account_transactions,
    class_name: 'Transaction',
    foreign_key: 'credit_account_id',
    dependent: :nullify
```

I want to make scope, that will be sort accounts by sum of transactions (debit_amount + credit_amount) and with using scope i will output total_amount for each account.

Now, i have next scope:

```rb
joins(:credit_account_transactions, :debit_account_transactions)
      .where('transactions.created_at >= ?', 1.month.ago)
      .select(
        'accounts.*',
        'SUM(transactions.debit_amount_cents) AS total_debit_amount',
        'SUM(transactions.credit_amount_cents) AS total_credit_amount',
        'SUM(transactions.credit_amount_cents + transactions.debit_amount_cents) AS total_amount'
      )
      .order('total_amount DESC')
      .group('accounts.id')
  end
```

But it doesn't work correctly.
It doesn't count `debit_amount`.

```rb
Account.accounts_balance.first.total_credit_amount
=> 1500
Account.accounts_balance.first.total_debit_amount 
=> 0
```

But if swap `:credit_account_transactions` and  `:debit_account_transactions` in `joins(:credit_account_transactions, :debit_account_transactions)` it will count `total_debit_amount`, and `total_credit_amount` - will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're joining the same table twice. They will be different and have to referenced differently. Rails tries to be smart and renames the 2nd join.

Run just `Account.joins(:credit_account_transactions, :debit_account_transactions)` and see what sql it produces. It will probably be something like:

```sql
SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts"
INNER JOIN "transactions"
  ON "transactions"."credit_account_id" = "accounts"."id"
INNER JOIN "transactions" "credit_account_transactions_accounts"
  ON "credit_account_transactions_accounts"."debit_account_id" = "accounts"."id";
```

Here you can see that the 2nd join is renamed to something different (`credit_account_transactions_accounts`) in this case and you have to reference it as such.

```rb
.select(
  'accounts.*',
  'SUM(transactions.debit_amount_cents) AS total_debit_amount',
  'SUM(credit_account_transactions_accounts.credit_amount_cents) AS total_credit_amount',
```